# Google Dataflow Out Of Heap When Creating Multiple Tagged Outputs

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have many large unpartitioned BigQuery tables and files that I would like to partition in various ways.  So I decided to try and write a Dataflow job to achieve this. The job I think is simple enough.  I tried to write with generics so that I easily apply it both TextIO and BigQueryIO sources.  It works fine with small tables, but I keep getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` when I run it on large tables.

In my main class I either read a file with target keys (made with another DF job) or run a query against a BigQuery table to get a list of keys to shard by.  My main class looks like this:

```java
Pipeline sharder = Pipeline.create(opts);

// a functional interface that shows the tag map how to get a tuple tag
KeySelector<String, TableRow> bqSelector = (TableRow row) -> (String) row.get("COLUMN") != null ? (String) row.get("COLUMN") : "null";

// a utility class to store a tuple tag list and hash map of String TupleTag
TupleTagMap<String, TableRow> bqTags = new TupleTagMap<>(new ArrayList<>(inputKeys),bqSelector);

// custom transorm
ShardedTransform<String, TableRow> bqShard = new ShardedTransform<String, TableRow>(bqTags, TableRowJsonCoder.of());

String source = "PROJECTID:ADATASET.A_BIG_TABLE";
String destBase = "projectid:dataset.a_big_table_sharded_";

TableSchema schema = bq.tables().get("PROJECTID","ADATASET","A_BIG_TABLE").execute().getSchema();


PCollectionList<TableRow> shards = sharder.apply(BigQueryIO.Read.from(source)).apply(bqShard);
for (PCollection<TableRow> shard : shards.getAll()) {
    String shardName = StringUtils.isNotEmpty(shard.getName()) ? shard.getName() : "NULL";
    shard.apply(BigQueryIO.Write.to(destBase + shardName)
            .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
            .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
            .withSchema(schema));
    System.out.println(destBase+shardName);
} 
sharder.run();
```

I generate a set of `TupleTags` to use in a custom transform. I created a utility class that stores a `TupleTagList` and `HashMap` so that I can reference the tuple tags by key:

```java
public class TupleTagMap<Key, Type> implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8762959703864266959L;
final private TupleTagList tList;
final private Map<Key, TupleTag<Type>> map;
final private KeySelector<Key, Type> selector;

public TupleTagMap(List<Key> t, KeySelector<Key, Type> selector) {
    map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Key key : t)
        map.put(key, new TupleTag<Type>());
    this.tList = TupleTagList.of(new ArrayList<>(map.values()));
    this.selector = selector;

}

public Map<Key, TupleTag<Type>> getMap() {
    return map;
}

public TupleTagList getTagList() {
    return tList;
}

public TupleTag<Type> getTag(Type t){
    return map.get(selector.getKey(t));
}
```

Then I have this custom transform that basically has a function that uses the tuple map to output `PCollectionTuple` and then moves it to a `PCollectionList` to return to the main class:

```java
public class ShardedTransform<Key, Type> extends
    PTransform<PCollection<Type>, PCollectionList<Type>> {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 3320626732803297323L;
private final TupleTagMap<Key, Type> tags;
private final Coder<Type> coder;


public ShardedTransform(TupleTagMap<Key, Type> tags, Coder<Type> coder) {
    this.tags = tags;
    this.coder = coder;
}

@Override
public PCollectionList<Type> apply(PCollection<Type> in) {

    PCollectionTuple shards = in.apply(ParDo.of(
            new ShardFn<Key, Type>(tags)).withOutputTags(
            new TupleTag<Type>(), tags.getTagList()));

    List<PCollection<Type>> shardList = new ArrayList<>(tags.getMap().size());

    for (Entry<Key, TupleTag<Type>> e : tags.getMap().entrySet()){
        PCollection<Type> shard = shards.get(e.getValue()).setName(e.getKey().toString()).setCoder(coder);
        shardList.add(shard);
    }
        return PCollectionList.of(shardList);
    } 
}
```

The actual DoFn is dead simple it just uses the lambda provided in the main class do find the matching tuple tag in the hash map for side output:

```java
public class ShardFn<Key, Type> extends DoFn<Type, Type> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 961325260858465105L;

private final TupleTagMap<Key, Type> tags;

ShardFn(TupleTagMap<Key, Type> tags) {

    this.tags = tags;
}

@Override
public void processElement(DoFn<Type, Type>.ProcessContext c)
        throws Exception {
    Type element = c.element();
    TupleTag<Type> tag = tags.getTag(element);

    if (tag != null)
        c.sideOutput(tags.getTag(element), element);
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is your worker machine type, at which stage is it OOMing? Also how big `bqTags` can get, maybe you should use side input to distribute `bqTags` (doc: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do#side-inputs)

Comment: I tried using n1-standard-4.  It seems like the the OOMs are happening in ShardedTransform or ShardFn.  As far as I can tell nothing is ever sent to the PCollections that are output from there.

There are 80 tags in the tag map for the large dataset.

Answer (score 1):

The Beam model doesn't have good support for dynamic partitioning / large numbers of partitions right now. Your approach chooses the number of shards at graph construction time, and then the resulting ParDos likely all fuses together, so you've got each worker trying to write to 80 different BQ tables at the same time. Each write requires some local buffering, so it's probably just too much.

There's an alternate approach which will do the parallelization across tables (but not across elements). This would work well if you have a large number of relatively small output tables. Use a ParDo to tag each element with the table it should go to and then do a GroupByKey. This gives you a `PCollection<KV<Table, Iterable<ElementsForThatTable>>>`. Then process each `KV<Table, Iterable<ElementsForThatTable>>` by writing the elements to the table.

Unfortunately for now you'll have to the BQ write by hand to use this option. We're looking at extending the Sink APIs with built in support for this. And since the Dataflow SDK is being further developed as part of Apache Beam, we're tracking that request here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-92

Comment: Thanks Frances.  I've seen a couple of SO post that suggest parallelizing across tables.  In my case I've got a smaller number of large output tables.  TBs of data that needs to be split into 80 tables.